# Java (de)serialization process

Tags: java, serialization

I am curious to know what happens when we de-serialize an object.

For example if my class object is composed of many other objects, how does the object creation process takes place in De-serialization process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects are created with default initialized fields and then populated with attribute values taken from the serial stream.  The object creation is done by runtime system "magic" rather than a declared (or implicit) constructor.